# Creating dynamic previous next buttons in jquery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, dialog

I have searched high and low for this on this site and the web

Is it possible to dynamically create previous and next buttons in a jquery dialog box?

I have a list of links, and I would like to click on a link and have a dialog box open. In that dialog box would have a previous and next button that when clicked on would close the current dialog box and open the previous or next item in the list in another dialog box and so on.

Somthing like this

HTML

```
<ul id="dialoglist">
  <li>
    <a href="list1.html">
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="list2.html">
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="list3.html">
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="list4.html">
  </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$("ul#dialoglist a").click(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('href') + " #content";
    var box = $('<div></div>').load(link).dialog({
        buttons: {
            "prev": function() {
                 $(this).dialog('close');
                 //open previous dialog
             },
             "next": function() {
                 $(this).dialog('close');
                 //open next dialog
             }
        }
    });
    $(box).dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$("ul#dialoglist a").click(function(){
    var a = $(this);
    var link = a.attr('href') + " #content";

    // move button creation here so we can dynamically build 
    // the button hash:

    var aParent = a.parent();
    var buttons = {};
    var prevLi = aParent.prev();
    var nextLi = aParent.next();

    if(prev.length > 0){
      buttons.prev = function(){
        // not sure if this is in the corret scope here - you may need to select by id
        $(this).dialog('close');
        $('a', prevLi).click();
      };
    }

    if(next.length > 0){
      buttons.next = function(){
        / not sure if this is in the corret scope here - you may need to select by id
        $(this).dialog('close');
        $('a', nextLi).click();
      };
    }

    var box = $('<div></div>').load(link).dialog({
        'buttons': buttons
    });
    $(box).dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

Since you just trigger the click event on the prev/next links you shouldnt have to worry about manually openeing the dialogs.

However... why open new dialogs instead of using the dialog widgets api to set the content directly?

Comment: That works!! Thank you so much. Man, I spent all day searching for this answer. I looked into the dialog widgets api, but had a hard time understanding the documentation. I think what you mean is reuse the closed dialog rather than create a new one with every click. I have only been using jQuery for a couple weeks and I have no prior knowledge of JavaScript

Comment: Just make sure you click the check mark to give me the answer... If you feel really generous you can click the up arrow as well :-)

Comment: No problem, will do. I am not trying to get greedy but, is there a way to hide the next button if you are at the end of the list?

Comment: Thanks, I marked this as answered. But I cant up it because I don't have a reputation.

Comment: ok updated.. as far as resuing the dialog you can just use `$(whatever).dialog().html('the new content');` to through differnt content in it, but then youll have to use `$(whatever).dialog('options', 'buttons', theNewButtonHash);` to refresh the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of new to Jquery, I have a bit of experience but not much, but the solution prodigitalson provided looks great, it just seems to me that since you are getting the click event, wouldn't you need to prevent the default link click? Otherwise, it will just try to follow the href provided in the anchor, right?

Sorry to post this as an answer, but my reputation isn't enough to post a comment...

Answer (score 0):

### JS

```
    $(function() {  
        /* construct prev/next button */
        $(".dialog div.dialogs").each(function (i) {
            var totalSize = $(".dialog div.dialogs").size() - 1;           
            if (i != 0) {
                prev = i - 1;
                $(this).append("<div class='prev_button'><a href='#tabs' class='prev-tab mover' rel='" + prev + "'>Previous</a></div>");
            }

             if (i != totalSize) {
                next = i + 1;
                $(this).append("<div class='next_button'><a href='#tabs' class='next-tab mover' rel='" + next + "'>Next</a></div>");
            }
        });

        /* next button click */
        $('.next-tab').click(function () {
              var nextDialog= $(this).parent().parent().data("id") + 1;  
              var currentDialog = $(this).parent().parent(); currentDialog.dialog("close");
              $("#dialog"+ nextDialog).dialog();
        });

        /* previous button click */
        $('.prev-tab').click(function () {
              var prevDialog = $(this).parent().parent().data("id") - 1;  
              var currentDialog = $(this).parent().parent(); currentDialog.dialog("close");
              $("#dialog"+ prevDialog).dialog();
        });

        /* intial dialog(first) */
        $( "#dialog1" ).dialog();   
  });
```

### HTML

```
<div class="dialog" style="display:none">
    <div id="dialog1" class="dialogs" data-id="1" title="dialog1">
      <p>Dialog content1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="dialog2" class="dialogs" data-id="2" title="dialog2">
      <p>Dialog content2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="dialog3" class="dialogs" data-id="3" title="dialog3">
      <p>Dialog content3</p>
    </div>
    <div id="dialog4" class="dialogs" data-id="4" title="dialog4">
      <p>Dialog content4</p>
    </div> 
</div>
```

### PLUGGINS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```